# Android 6.x wifi restriction work around

Tags: java, android

This new restriction on Android 6.0. If the wifi you are connected to doesn't have internet access, it alerts you to choose whether you want to keep connected, and if you select no, or you don't make a selection, the phone will be disconnected, and get connected back to your 3G/4G or another wifi. For real world users, a lot of them won't even pay attention to that alert message. Is there a workaround to override this restriction? I need the wifi with no internet connection, and i do not want the users to have to deal with selecting whether they have to keep connected. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect it uses `ping` or a similar technique to figure out if it has Internet access. Since I can't find the exact details, you'll probably have to figure out exactly what address needs to respond and set up a responder of some kind at that address on your network.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson , I have an IP camera which acts like a wifi hotspot for it to receive commands from the app. My users will each have there own camera. How will this method work for them. Thanks.